# tkinter only works via functions?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've made a tic tac toe game using PyCharm IDE. I've tried to make it run with tkinter but i got some issues.

My program asks the user to choose between X and O , also if X plays first or second. Also if u were to put incorrect answer the program would tell the user to retype his/her answer (with a while statement). On tkinter I can't make that, for example when the program asks "Do you want X or O" and the user types X and then `ok_button`, it does not store that information anywhere. And if I try to put in a `while` loop, it goes on an infinity loop (since it loops through the first answer the user clicked `ok`)

My question is how can I create a sequence since tkinter runs with classes and functions (at least i dont know something else). For example: Program asks *"Do you want to be X or O?"*, after putting correct input to entry, the program should ask *"Do you want to go first or second?"*.

```
from tkinter import *

def name_choose(x):
     # "print" message to Label
     message["text"] = player_decide(x)[2]
     # how do i store that info below ? so i can use it later
     player_1 =player_decide(x)[0]    
     player_2 =player_decide(x)[1]


window = Tk()
....
message = Label(window_frame1)
message.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=1)

entry = Entry(window_frame1)
entry.place(relx=0.55, relwidth=0.2, relheight=1)

button_Ok = Button(window_frame1, text="Ok", command = lambda: name_choose(entry.get()) )
button_Ok.place(relx=0.8, relwidth=0.2, relheight=1)

....
window.mainloop()

def player_decide(player_1):
    player_2 = ""
    if player_1.upper() == "X":
        message = "Player 1 : X , Player 2 : O"
        player_2 = "O"
        game_status = 1
    elif player_1.upper() == "O":
        player_2 = "X"
        message = "Player 1 : O , Player 2 : X"
        game_status = 1
    else:
        message = "Retry Input"
        game_status = 0
    return player_1, player_2, message , game_status
```

Comment: You cannot place functions after the `mainloop()`.

Comment: (it was is on another page ) , i just added it down there to show u . i have not funtionts under mainloop

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def name_choose(x):
     # "print" message to Label
     message["text"] = player_decide(x)[2]
     # how do i store that info below ? so i can use it later
     player_1 =player_decide(x)[0]    
     player_2 =player_decide(x)[1]


window = Tk()
....
message = Label(window_frame1)
message.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=1)

entry = Entry(window_frame1)
entry.place(relx=0.55, relwidth=0.2, relheight=1)

button_Ok = Button(window_frame1, text="Ok", command = lambda: name_choose(entry.get()) )
button_Ok.place(relx=0.8, relwidth=0.2, relheight=1)

....
def player_decide(player_1):
    player_2 = ""
    if player_1.upper() == "X":
        message = "Player 1 : X , Player 2 : O"
        player_2 = "O"
        game_status = 1
    elif player_1.upper() == "O":
        player_2 = "X"
        message = "Player 1 : O , Player 2 : X"
        game_status = 1
    else:
        message = "Retry Input"
        game_status = 0
    return player_1, player_2, message , game_status

window.mainloop()
```

The problem was because you had the function defined after the mainloop. Make sure all the code is run before the mainloop starts.